# Перестал работать openserver

Tags: php, apache, nginx, http, openserver

Сидел себе спокойно работал, обновлял страницу в браузере дабы отслеживать изменения и вдруг (Не удается получить доступ к сайту) смотрю флажок стал красный, думаю странно никогда такого не было чтобы опен сервер сам отваливался, включаю его заново а он стоит на оранжевом флажке где-то минуту и снова красный. в логе какая то дичь, ничего конкретного

```
2020-11-04 17:30:52  --------------------------------------------
2020-11-04 17:30:52  Начало процедуры запуска сервера
2020-11-04 17:30:52  Обновление Hosts файла
2020-11-04 17:30:52  Обновление конфигурации Sendmail
2020-11-04 17:30:52  Обновление конфигурации PHP_7.1-x64
2020-11-04 17:30:52  Обновление конфигурации Apache_2.4-PHP_7.0-7.1-x64
2020-11-04 17:30:52  Запуск Apache_2.4-PHP_7.0-7.1-x64
2020-11-04 17:30:52  Проверка состояния сервера
2020-11-04 17:31:33  Не удалось запустить Apache_2.4-PHP_7.0-7.1-x64
2020-11-04 17:31:33  Сбой запуска!
2020-11-04 17:31:33  --------------------------------------------
2020-11-04 17:31:33  Начало процедуры остановки сервера
2020-11-04 17:31:33  Остановка системных модулей
2020-11-04 17:31:34  Отключение виртуального диска
2020-11-04 17:31:34  Сервер успешно остановлен за 0,5 секунд!
```

от имени администратора запускал не помогло, версии apache, php и nginx все перепробовал ни одна не открывается у меня windows 10 x64 может кто сталкивался поделитесь как побороть

Comment: Такая же проблема вчера возникла, до сих пор не исправил

Comment: Логи апача курили? Что они говорят?

Comment: логи апача пустые

Comment: Качайте заново и отключайте автоматическое обновление.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте запустить сервер в агрессивном режиме. OpenServer->Настройки->Сервер...

Если не выйдет, думаю нужно обратиться в поддержку OpenServer или скачать новую версию..